I get multiple location results when asking for the GeocodingResponse, how to choose one?
Currently I am using the Google API quite often but this is the first time I stumble across amiguity in the addresses. I recieve an ovject with 2 Geocoding location results for the same address I put.
The following address: "Eigentalstrasse 17, 8425 Oberembrach ZH, CH" returns me double results:

"Eigentalstrasse 17, 8425 Oberembrach, Switzerland" 
"ChIJQaKuy1aemkcR-Dm4JovK9ok"
"47.48557839999999", "8.619296799999999"
"types" : ["street_address"]

"Eigentalstrasse 17, 8425 Oberembrach, Switzerland"
"ChIJOw3Tq3yfmkcR-xU4w4gzMCY"
"47.4855703", "8.6193229" 
"types": ["establishment", "point_of_interest"]

I am not usre which one to pick? Since the application logic expects only one response result It behaves strange when I recieve two of them, so I would need to filter them by something. The problem is that I want to make this a general rule for all ambiguities in the Google DB.
The question is on which property should I filter?
Should I use the types array? And search only for the ones with the status - "street_address"? Do all addresses in Google DB have street address. How should I deal with that please help!
Everyhting is explained above
